# Accessing GLTF "Extension" or "Extras" property in UNITY engine

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, gltf

I am currently using the SicCity GLTF importer for Unity. I have gltf files that uses the extras tag. I am having issue finding out how to access this property in UNITY. The documentation is a bit scarce.

My question is how to access this property when the JSON is de-serialized in UNITY